# scala treeset fails to remove element

Tags: scala, treeset, red-black-tree

I'm using a scala.collection.mutable.TreeSet and I'm running into a problem, where it fails to remove an element when `-=` is called.

My code:

```
val discovered = new TreeSet[Position]()(Ordering by { position => estimation(position) })
//Position is defined as: type Position = (Int, Int)

discovered += start
var x = 0
while(!discovered.isEmpty){
  val current = discovered.head
  println(discovered)
  discovered -= current
  println(discovered)
  x += 1
  println(s"$x $current")

  [...] //Code to process current and discover new positions
}
```

The following example shows, that (18,46) is not removed. Up until that point the removing worked perfectly. I have other test cases, which work perfecly and other cases where this problem does not happen until about 100 iterations are reached. I've got the same result with the immutable implementation of `TreeSet`.

Part of the output:

```
TreeSet((22,42), (18,46), (21,44), (24,46), (22,47), (21,43), (21,47), (23,47), (24,47))
TreeSet((18,46), (21,44), (24,46), (22,47), (21,43), (21,47), (23,47), (24,47))
14 (22,42)
TreeSet((18,46), (21,44), (22,41), (24,46), (22,47), (21,43), (21,47), (23,47), (24,47))
TreeSet((18,46), (21,44), (22,41), (24,46), (22,47), (21,43), (21,47), (23,47), (24,47))
15 (18,46)
TreeSet((18,46), (21,44), (22,41), (24,46), (22,47), (21,43), (21,47), (23,47), (24,47), (17,46))
TreeSet((18,46), (21,44), (22,41), (24,46), (22,47), (21,43), (21,47), (23,47), (24,47), (17,46))
16 (18,46)
```

Comment: How is estimation(position) defined? Perhaps the ordering is not robust?

Comment: `val estimation = new HashMap[Position, Float].withDefaultValue(Float.PositiveInfinity)`
And `discovered` is always updated when estimation changes:
`estimation(somePosition) = newScore;
if(alreadyDiscovered){ discovered -= somePosition }
discovered += somePosition`

Comment: Is this a mutable hashmap? Are there any values filled in it?

Comment: Yes the HashMap is: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.
`estimation` is initially empty (defaults to +Infinity) and filled inside the loop.

Comment: Only the value for `start` is defined before the loop:
`estimation(start) = someFloat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your answers! The ordering was related to the problem, so it helped a lot to find the error.

Clarification:

I'm implementing a lot of my code base fully functional. For this algorithm it was not possible for several reasons. Also: If there was a PriorityQueue, that had an updateElement() function, I would have used that instead of the TreeSet for better performance and to avoid the problem I ran into.

My solution:

As said: I have to implement it mutable and mostly imperative. The problem was in those lines of code

```
estimation(somePosition) = newScore
if(alreadyDiscovered){ discovered -= somePosition }
discovered += somePosition
```

Removing `somePosition` from `discovered` is making use of the ordering, which was changed in the line above. So when the RB tree tries to delete the element it does not find it anymore. **The following code is working for all test cases**

```
if(alreadyDiscovered){ discovered -= somePosition }
estimation(somePosition) = newScore
discovered += somePosition
```

If there is a better data structure than TreeSet in vanilla scala for this task I would love to switch to that.

Comment: Don't post comments as answers. Edit your original answer instead. Or delete it if it is not relevant any longer.  To answer yoyr question, there are lots of structures in "vanilla scala", it is not possible to tell which of them are " better" than TreeSet, because that quality would depend on a specific purpose. In any event, your problem is not that the TreeSet is a "bad data structure", but rather that your implementation is bad. And no, you don't _have to_ implement it this way, you simply _choose_ to do it.

Comment: That's not a comment, but the answer: So the topic is done for me. I'll not delete it, because it could help someone else.
As I stated: I don't think TreeSet is a bad data structur, but it is not a perfect fit for the task I want to accomplish. It's still a quite good fit, but a pqueue with update (those exist in other frameworks) would be better. I've done a lot of research and vanilla scala does not contain such a collection.
I find it a bit rude to say my implementation is bad, without knowing the code base or context (like problem statement).

Comment: It's not rude. Any implementation, that relies on an ordered set with an unstable ordering is bad, regardless of the codebase (maybe the whole codebase is bad, that I don't know) or problem statement. Any problem can be solved in a good way or in a bad way, that is irrelevant. A good implementation is not so much a matter of picking a good data structure (although, that us also important) as it is of designing a proper, correct and efficient algorithm, and implementing it in a robust and reliable way.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your ordering isn't stable,  the relation between two given elements may change while the code is running, making the contents of the tree invalid (you did not expect  the elements of the tree to get reordered every time you update your hash map, did you?).

I think, you should consider throwing out what you have entirely, and rethinking your approach from the beginning. It might help to try implementing it in functional terms, avoiding the use of vars and mutable structures, besides making your code cleaner and clearer,  it would also help you avoid mistakes like this one.